# Replacing a file in Google Docs

Tags: google-drive

Is there any way to replace the uploaded (unconverted) PDF file?

For example, I have a PDF file and I realized that there were some typos in it, so I wish to upload the revised file in place of the original one.

The intention is to use the same share address as the original file but make it point to the revised one.

Comment: I don't know a way to do this in Docs (and would be very interested to hear if you find one). This issue is why I've actually used a File Store in Google Sites as a place to host a large number of files that I share: In Sites, if you upload a file with the same name, it will automatically replace the old version.

Answer (score 8):

Buried in the help pages for Google docs I did find a page that discusses [uploading multiple versions of a file](http://support.google.com/docs/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190564&topic=1360907&ctx=topic)

> You can upload different versions of the same file to your Documents List and easily keep track of them by selecting the Add or manage versions... option (or View versions... if you have viewing permission only).
>
> This feature lets you upload new versions of a file, as well as download previous versions of it, and delete older versions. It makes it easier overall to collaborate on a file with other people. Each version counts toward your total Google Docs storage quota, so you should clean out older versions every once in a while.
>
> This feature is available for uploaded files that are not in Google Docs format. For Google Docs, you can use the revision history, which lets you see all the different versions of a doc.

Answer (score 8):

You can also try this:

1. Tick the document
2. Select **More**
3. Go to **Manage Revisions**
4. Upload your updated version

Comment: I tried what was given because I have the same problem-- but there is no option for "manage revisions" after I tick the document and then select more... so I'm wondering what to do now..

Comment: You'll need to select 'More' in the upper navigation (not in the left navigation) - Manage Revisions is found there.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

1. Open the document
2. Go to the menu *File* → *Open*
3. Upload the new version file.

Answer (score 0):

As above, "This feature is available for uploaded files that are *not in Google Docs format*. For Google Docs, you can use the revision history, which lets you see all the different versions of a doc."

As a workaround, to replace or update a Google Doc (.gsheet) file, you can upload and open a new version on Google Docs or Sheets and then copy / paste the content into the old version.

Comment: "As above" doesn't have much context, since answers can be sorted in multiple ways. Better to link to the answer to which you are referring.